# Laravel not finding classes that should be included

Tags: php, laravel, web, frameworks

I am new to Laravel and working on a simple project. At first, I was having trouble with classes not being found because of needing to namespace at first, but figured that out quickly. Now I am running into a problem where it won't find classes which i'm trying to inherit from no matter how they are namespaced.

So basically:

```
require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Modelcontainer.php');
class ListOrderItemsRequest extends Model ......
```

Throws the error that model cannot be found even though its included right there.

And if i go to the mocelcontainer.php and namespace it, it still doesn't work!

Thank you very much

Comment: Read about namespaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in Laravel 5 is autoloaded using `PSR-4`, within the `app/` directory. You can see this in the `composer.json` file. so In the `Laravel` framework, you do not need to use `require_once` to load classes.

Basically, you could create another directory within `app`, and then `namespace` your files in there as appropriate:

`/app/MyServices/Sms.php`

Then, within your Sms.php, make sure you namespace it:

`namespace App\MyServices;`

Now, you can access this class using the namespace within your classes:

`use App\MyServices\Sms.php;`

Comment: Thank you i did not know any of that and it gives me a great place to work from. If you dont mind, why do you have to namespace it app\myservices, does the namespace need to point to the containing folder? and additionally, why does it shift from forward to backslash?

Comment: i suggest read more about `namespace` in php : https://www.sitepoint.com/php-53-namespaces-basics/

Comment: did that^ and got it working finally! Thank you very much. One last question, now laravel is reading a class that extends "Exception" ( a built in php class) and saying it can't find exception even though it is native to php. How could i stop this?

Comment: Never mind! use exception; right before worked perfect